# Re-using results from webservice

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am using Java and SOAP. 
I have two webservices. One (A), which generates some data, and one (B), which will update that data given specific parameters. 
My question is: How can I save the data after it is generated from A for B to use? 
I have read that using stateful webservices is not preferable. Instead, can I just write the XML response to a file and then get B to open and parse that file? This seems like a lot of work. What would be the 'normal' method to use here?

Thank you!

Comment: Are A and B both externally facing, and B needs to update internally generated data resulting from an external call to A? Or does A's client end up with the data, and then pass it on to B?

Comment: Yes, they are both externally facing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual enterprisey thing to do is to have a persistence layer (e.g. database) to save the data. You would map the XML to a relational model and store that, then regenerate the XML when B requires it.

Saving a file directly is pretty simple and might be the best solution - you'll need to manage locking etc. yourself. Or you could do a very simple DB with the XML in a column.